# SUBCONSULTA + JOIN SQL

Tags: sql

Hola buenas tengo que realizar una sub consulta incluida con un inner join el cual no me puede derivar ninguna resultado es con hr de sql developer este seria mi codigo

```
SELECT e.employee_id "NUMERO EMPLEADO",
e.first_name "PRIMER NOMBRE", e.last_name "APELLIDO",
 j.job_title
FROM EMPLOYEES e
 INNER JOIN jobs j
 ON j.job_id = e.job_id
where j.job_title =(SELECT 
                    CASE WHEN job_title='Programmer' 
                    THEN 'IT' Else job_title end
                    FROM JOBS)
                    ;
```

---

---

no me funciona el codigo me tira error de ante mano gracias
y me piden lo sgte
"Se necesita conocer al personal que realiza tareas de programación, para ello se requiere que muestre el ID del empleado, el nombre, el apellido y el nombre del departamento al que pertenecen todos los empleados que como JOB_TITTLE tengan ‘Programmer’" y me pide cambiar 'Programmer' por 'IT'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nose si te sirva de algo ahora:`SELECT e.employee_id "NUMERO DE EMPLEADO", e.first_name"NOMBRE", e.last_name "APELLIDO", SUBSTR(e.job_id,1,2) "NOMBRE DEL DEPARTAMENTO" FROM employees e JOIN jobs j  ON e.job_id = j.job_id and j.job_title = 'Programmer' ORDER by e.employee_id desc;`

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo funciona la consulta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

según lo que entiendo esto podría ser lo que necesitas:

```
SELECT
    e.employee_id "NUMERO EMPLEADO",
    e.first_name "PRIMER NOMBRE",
    e.last_name "APELLIDO",
    'IT' "TITULO",
    d.department_name 'DEPARTAMENTO'
FROM
    employees e
    INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = e.job_id
    INNER JOIN departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
WHERE
    j.job_title = 'Programmer'
```

Espero haberte ayudado en algo, sino espero tus comentarios.
Saludos!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).